# Посчитать все возможные варианты сочетаний строк

Tags: java, комбинаторика

Есть 5000 строк в массиве. Нужно перебрать все возможные варианты в ряде из 10 вариантов, при этом порядок в ряде не важен. К примеру:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 = 10,9,8,6,7,5,4,3,2,1 = 8,9,10,7,6,4,5,3,1,2 - Одни и те же ряды.

В каждом уникальном ряду ещё нужно будет выполнить несколько арифметических рассчётов. Возможно ли реализовать такое или не получиться выполнить такое большое количество операций? А если возможно, то как такое лучше сделать?

Comment: C_5000^10 = (5000!)/(10!*4990!) - число сочетаний

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Количество сочетаний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) равно биномиальному коэффициенту С<sup>10</sup><sub>5000</sub>

С<sup>10</sup><sub>5000</sub> = 5000! / (10! * 4990!) = 2667017604016906260066258312000 ≈ 2*10<sup>30</sup>

Навряд ли это все получится перебрать. Если перебирать по миллиарду комбинаций в секунду, то на это уйдет, по моим грубым подсчетам, 60 триллионов лет.

Если все-таки понадобится перебор сочетаний, посмотрите варианты здесь: [How to iteratively generate k elements subsets from a set of size n in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504974/how-to-iteratively-generate-k-elements-subsets-from-a-set-of-size-n-in-java). Обратите внимание на класс [`Combinations`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Combinations.html) из Apache Commons.

Comment: Долговато ждать придётся( Спасибо за ответ, жаль что не получиться реализовать

Comment: Как вы не перебирают, произвольным образом. Добавите логику число резко сократится

Comment: @НикитаМостоцкий Да, нужно подумать над алгоритмом. Скорее всего количество сочетаний можно сократить.

Comment: А ещё перебор ваш легко распараллеливается

Comment: так что этот ответ так себе.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Ну да, осталось построить кластер на триллион ядер :)

Comment: @AzizUmarov `так что этот ответ так себе. ` вот пишете такое, а потом жалуетесь, что у людей к Вам неприязнь :)

Comment: А что противозаконного? Вы человеку сразу своим ответом всё отрезали. И считаете его хорошим?

Comment: К стати я не жаловался вы брешите, а спросил мнение. Жаловаться - это писать вверх начальству чтоб приняли меры. А вот вы судите без суда.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Человек спросил можно ли подсчитать в лоб, я ответил что нельзя. Дальше сам будет думать. Если можете ответить лучше, отвечайте. Если что-то не нравится в ответе, расскажите как его можно улучшить, я послушаю. P.S. [жаловаться](http://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=7592) — высказывать жалобы

Comment: А если к примеру сократить количество строк в массиве с 5000 до 70-100, это сильно изменит ситуацию? 1646492110120, а то такое количество переборов тоже пугает.

Comment: @НикитаМостоцкий я тоже об этом, потому что никто про подсчет в лоб не писал. А ответы по типу такой да и ещё принятые как полезный собственно мотивацию у людей поубавит писать.

Comment: @НикитаМостоцкий Не совсем понял как получилось 1646492110120, но это по крайней мере выполнимый расчет. Может зададите новый вопрос в котором расскажете про задачу в целом? Вполне возможно, что кто-то предложит более оптимальный вариант.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да бросьте, все отвечают, а у Вас мотивации нет :) Напишите ответ, может поможете человеку. Если будет что-то хорошее сам плюс поставлю.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да мне просто самому казалось это нереальным, поэтому сразу и принял, не вдаваясь в подробности. Сейчас новый создам, немного распишу поподробнее.

Comment: @defaultlocale писать что угодно собственно не собираюсь и не надо. Задача с наскока вот так не решается. Направить или подать идеи могу, но обрезать не стану, могу лишь ответить что комбинаторные задачи в общем хоть и выглядят страшными в реалии ими в лоб не пользуются.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Совершенно верно, нужно менять алгоритм. Не думаю что можно что-то посоветовать без описания задачи. Сейчас автор напишет тогда может и будут варианты.

Comment: @defaultlocale Уже написал и сократил количество элементов в массиве :)

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да я просто понимаю, что то слишком нереально звучит, 5000 то было бы в идеале, но 60-100 элементов тоже в принципе подойдёт. Но меньше уже смысла нету делать

Comment: @НикитаМостоцкий я добавил комментарий в новый вопрос